# Не получается заменить элемент строки

Tags: python

```
N = int(input())
N = str(N)
kr3 = []
for i in range (len(N)):
    for j in range (1,10):
        N[i] = N[i].replace (N[i], str(j))
        if int(N) % 3 == 0:
            kr3.append (int(N))

print (max(N))
```

Формат входных данных
В первой строке записано натуральное число, не превышающее 10^100
.
Формат выходных данных
Выведите наибольшее число, кратное трём, отличающееся от исходного ровно одной цифрой.
Пример
стандартный поток ввода стандартный поток вывода
123 723

Выдает ошибку: str object does not support item assignment.

Comment: Зачем сначала переводить строковый input в int, а затем опять в str? ну и самое главное: строки в python  являются immutable, то есть не изменяемыми. переведите строку в список и работайте с ним, либо сразу в число переводите.

Comment: Незачем, я затупил просто.

Comment: Если делать это с помощью функции .split(), то это будет список с одним элементом.

Comment: @MontyPython `list('123') = ['1', '2', '3']` `''.join(['1', '2', '3']) = '123'`

Answer (score 4):

**Основной посыл**: *число кратно трем, если сумма цифр в нем кратна трем*.

```
def find_max(value):
    data = list(value)

    for index in range(len(data)):
        if data[index] != '9':
            tmp = data[index]
            data[index] = str(9 - sum(map(int, data[:index] + data[index + 1:])) % 3)
            result = ''.join(data)
            if result > value:
                return result
            data[index] = tmp

    return value[:-1] + '6'


print(find_max('123'))    # 723
print(find_max('7000'))   # 9000
print(find_max('1111'))   # 9111
print(find_max('93556'))  # 98556
print(find_max('1'))      # 9
print(find_max('999'))    # 996
```

Answer (score 1):

может, проще будет сделать так:

```
b = '123'

variants = [[int(b[:y]+str(x)+b[y+1:]) for x in range(int(b[y]),10)] for y in range(len(b))]
res = max(set([(x if x%3==0 else 0) for y in variants for x in y]))
print(res)
```

> 723

**UPDATE**

Как было отмечено в комментарии,код выше неверно отрабатывается пограничные значения. Дополнил:

```
b = '999'

variants = [[int(b[:y]+str(x)+b[y+1:]) for x in range((int(b[y]) if b[y]!='9' else 1),10)] for y in range(len(b))]
res = max(set([(x if x%3==0 else 0) for y in variants for x in y])-set([int(b)]))
print(res)
```

> 996

Comment: Круто. Code style за который коллеги похлопают по плечу роялем :)

Comment: Прогнал ваше решение на своих тестах. При `9` и `999` даёт неправильный результат. Должно возвращать   "наибольшее число, кратное трём, **отличающееся от исходного ровно одной цифрой**", а возращает числа состоящие из 9-ок неизменными, вместо `6` и `996`.

Comment: @MiniMax ну для этого и тест прогонять не надо было, все и так было понятно. тем не менее, я дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_multiple_of_three(number):
    remainder = int(number) % 3                              #(1)  
    need_to_three = (3 - remainder)                          #(2)

    for digit in number:
        new_digit =  need_to_three + int(digit)              #(3)

        multiplier = (9 - new_digit) // 3                    #(4)
        new_digit += multiplier * 3                          #(5)

        if digit != '9':
            return number.replace(digit, str(new_digit), 1)  #(6)

    return number[:-1] + '6'
```

**Логика решения следующая:**

1. Чтобы выяснить, сколько числу не хватает до кратности трём, узнаём остаток от деления на **3** - выражение **#(1)** и вычитаем его из **3** - выражение **#(2)**.
2. [Признак делимости на три](http://math-prosto.ru/?page=pages/delimost/delimost2.php) - "Число делится на 3, если сумма всех его цифр делится на 3". Следовательно, мы можем сделать число кратным **3**, прибавив нехватающее значение (полученное в предыдущем шаге) к любой цифре этого числа - **#(3)**. А так как нам нужно максимальное число, то прибавлять мы должны к цифре с самым большим разрядом.
3. Тут есть одна загвоздка: мы можем заменить цифру, сделав число кратным трём, но не получив при этом максимального числа.

   **Например**, имеем число `121`. Ему до кратности трём не хвает `2`. Прибавляем `2` к цифре `1` и получаем число `321`. Но это число не является максимальным. Максимальным в этом случае будет `921`. Для получения правильного результата, необходимо после выполнения шага **№2**, продолжать увеличивать целевую цифру на `3` до тех пор, пока эта цифра меньше или равна `9`. Я сделал это, вычислив количество добавляемых `3` - **#(4)** и далее применив этот множитель - **#(5)**.
4. Как только подходящая цифра найдена, заменяем её в исходной строке и возвращем результат - **#(6)**.

---

**Другой вариант решения.** Суть таже, только вместо **3** используем **9**.

```
def max_multiple_of_three(number):
    remainder = int(number) % 9
    for digit in number:
        new_digit = int(digit) + 9 - remainder

        if new_digit > 9:
            new_digit -= 3
        elif new_digit < 7:
            new_digit += 3

        if digit != '9':
            return number.replace(digit, str(new_digit), 1)

    return number[:-1] + '6'
```

**Тесты:**

```
print(max_multiple_of_three('0'))     # 9 
print(max_multiple_of_three('1'))     # 9 
print(max_multiple_of_three('9'))     # 6 
print(max_multiple_of_three('11'))    # 81
print(max_multiple_of_three('20'))    # 90
print(max_multiple_of_three('50'))    # 90

print(max_multiple_of_three('123'))    # 723
print(max_multiple_of_three('7000'))   # 9000
print(max_multiple_of_three('1111'))   # 9111
print(max_multiple_of_three('93556'))  # 98556
print(max_multiple_of_three('999'))    # 996
```